# Can not play sound in VLC and browser simultanously

Tags: sound, google-chrome, vlc

I have sound problem in VLC, if a video is playing in a browser and i launch an audio or video file in VLC i got this error message = "Audio output failed:
The audio device "sysdefault:CARD=MID" could not be used:
Device or resource busy.", it plays sound only if there is no sound playing in the browser !!!!!
i have VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax , and chrome browser

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Is pulseaudio installed?

Comment: ubuntu 15.04, and pulseaudio is installed version 6.0

Comment: I believe that JACK might be a good alternate, doesn't it have a mixer of a sort? It seems like your audio card can only handle one channel at a time. What model do you have?

Comment: i did  **cat /proc/asound/cards**  and this is the output i got:
' 0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                      HDA Intel MID at 0xfc800000 irq 28
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xddefc000 irq 17 '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  found a solution:

In VLC I went to tools --> preferences, then switched audio output to AUTOMATIC instead of ALSA and click the save button below.

Comment: This is not default. But now it goes to pulseaudio.

Comment: after choosing AUTOMATIC , click the save button below

Comment: You can [edit] your post.